# Extracting a subset of attributes with JSONPath

Tags: json, jsonpath

I have this JSON code:

```
{
    "A": {
        "AB": [{
            "ABA": "0",
            "ABB": "1",
            "ABC": "2"
        }]
    }
}
```

I need to use a JSONPath expression that returns that JSON with only ABA and ABC attributes. Something like:

```
{
    "A": {
        "AB": [{
            "ABA": "0",
            "ABC": "2"
        }]
    }
}
```

So far I manage to extract either one or all attributes. For example

```
$.A.AB[*]
```

or

```
$.A.AB[*].ABA
```

Is there a way to extract only two?

Thanks

Answer (score 49):

This will work using the Jayway implementation (Java):

```
$.A.AB[*]['ABB', 'ABA']
```

and the result for your input would be:

```
[
   {
      "ABB" : "1",
      "ABA" : "0"
   }
]
```

You can Compare different providers here:

http://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Thanks!
 I'm using the JSON Utils plugin with Jetbrains (Webstorm) and your pattern worked nicely to retrieve a couple of values from a lottie file
layers[?(@.nm=='ang_eyebr_r')]['ip', 'op']

Comment: The Jayway JsonPath feature to extract a subset of members from a json object is actually a bug in the Jayway JsonPath parser, see https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath/issues/395.

Comment: Just a quick note here, but on clients such as Insomnia, you can have spaces between the keys.

Comment: I believe @securisec means you **can't** have spaces between the keys in Insomnia.

Comment: In Insomnia you can't have spaces or quotes.  So the above would be `$.A.AB[*][ABB,ABA]`

Comment: Thanks everyone for the Insomnia comments which solved my issue that was driving me crazy.