# Selecting a subset of JSON properties and values using JSONPath

Tags: java, json, jsonpath

Given a JSON like:

```json
{
  "a":1,
  "b":2,
  "c":3,
  "d":4,
  "e":5
}
```

How can I select out `b`, `d` and `e` to get the following JSON?

```json
{
  "b":2,
  "d":4,
  "e":5
}
```

I want a JSON object and NOT only `2`, `4` and `5` values?

This is what I'm trying with and failing:

```
$.[b,d,e]
```

Comment: JSONPath is not suitable for that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extracting a subset of attributes with JSONPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27447781/extracting-a-subset-of-attributes-with-jsonpath)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JSONPath is not suitable for what you are trying to achieve: JSONPath is designed to select values and not key-value pairs. What you want could be achieved with Jackson or any JSON parser for Java.

If you want to go for Jackson here's the code that will do the trick:

```java
String json = "{\"a\":1,\"b\":2,\"c\":3,\"d\":4,\"e\":5}";

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode tree = mapper.readTree(json);

ObjectNode node = mapper.createObjectNode();
node.set("b", tree.get("b"));
node.set("d", tree.get("d"));
node.set("e", tree.get("e"));

String result = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(node);
```

Answer (score 2):

Elements must be in single quotes.

```
$.['b','d','e']
```

*Works fine for JsonPath from com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:2.4.0*

Answer (score 1):

Your json path is correct, while `json` it self is not. It should be:

```
{
"a":1,
"b":2,
"c":3,
"d":4,
"e":5
}
```

BTW there is good online testing resources for these purposes: http://jsonpath.com/

Comment: Using the given example and your link, the output is

```
[
  2,
  4,
  5
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your JSON to (as said by Andremoniy)

```
{
"a":1,
"b":2,
"c":3,
"d":4,
"e":5
}
```

and to select b,d,e use this

```
$.b,d,e
```