# How to get this using json path?

Tags: jsonpath

```
{
"store": {
    "book": [
        {
            "category": "reference",
            "author": "Nigel Rees",
            "title": "Sayings of the Century",
            "price": 8.95
        },
        {
            "category": "fiction",
            "author": "Evelyn Waugh",
            "title": "Sword of Honour",
            "price": 12.99
        },
        {
            "category": "fiction",
            "author": "Herman Melville",
            "title": "Moby Dick",
            "isbn": "0-553-21311-3",
            "price": 8.99
        },
        {
            "category": "fiction",
            "author": "J. R. R. Tolkien",
            "title": "The Lord of the Rings",
            "isbn": "0-395-19395-8",
            "price": 22.99
        }
    ],
    "bicycle": {
        "color": "red",
        "price": 19.95
    }
},
"expensive": 10
}
```

What if I need both author and title of all the books? Like rather than having the complete data about the book if I only want some detail of it how can I get that?

Comment: This is not possible using JSONPath. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40017445/selecting-a-subset-of-json-properties-and-values-using-jsonpath) answer

Comment: @MortezaBandi I don't want key-value pair I only want these values in single JSON path?
    [{''author-name,book-name}]

Comment: Ok then, @Jack Fleeting 's answer is what you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on the implementation, this

```
$..book[*]['title','author']
```

should get you close enough.

Comment: Interesting. Do you know which parsers support this? Thanks

Comment: It looks like it's a matter of which implementation of jasonpath you're using: the expression works with 3 of the 4 implementations (with 2 different results, naturally...). That's why I'm not a big fan of jsonpath: https://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/ (unfortunately, there's no way to save the example so you'll have to input it manually).